# SwiftUI: How to

Tags: ios, image, swiftui, firebase-storage, local

I am trying to upload a video to firebase Storage, to be able to do that I have to get the following:

```
let localFile = URL(string: "path/to/video")!
```

and then upload it with:

```
let uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(from: localFile
```

My problem is that I dont know how to get that path. So far I have a have a custom image / video picker, and then a function that can upload images. I just dont know how to upload Videos, for that I believe i need to get the path.

Any ideas on how to get **localFile**?

**UPDATE:**
This is my custom Picker

```
import SwiftUI
import PhotosUI

class ImagePickerViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // MARK: Properties
    @Published var fetchedImages: [ImageAsset] = []
    @Published var selectedImages: [ImageAsset] = []
    
    init(){
        fetchImages()
    }
    
    // MARK: Fetching Images
    func fetchImages(){
        let options = PHFetchOptions()
        // MARK: Modify As Per Your Wish
        options.includeHiddenAssets = false
        options.includeAssetSourceTypes = [.typeUserLibrary]
        options.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: options).enumerateObjects { asset, _, _ in
            let imageAsset: ImageAsset = .init(asset: asset)
            self.fetchedImages.append(imageAsset)
        }
        PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: options).enumerateObjects { asset, _, _ in
            let imageAsset: ImageAsset = .init(asset: asset)
            self.fetchedImages.append(imageAsset)
        }
    }
}
```

**On my view I have this:**

```
 .popupImagePicker(show: $showPicker) { assets in
            // MARK: Do Your Operation With PHAsset
            // I'm Simply Extracting Image
            // .init() Means Exact Size of the Image
            let manager = PHCachingImageManager.default()
            let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
            
            options.isSynchronous = true
            
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
                assets.forEach { asset in
                    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: .init(), contentMode: .default, options: options) { image, _ in
                        guard let image = image else {return}
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.pickedImages.append(image)
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You say you have a "custom image / video picker", but you don't show any code for it. That picker is what is likely responsible, one way or another, for providing you a reference to the file.

Comment: oh is it through the picker I have to get the path? @jnpdx

Comment: @jnpdx I made an update to show my custom picker

Comment: With a PHAsset, you may find it easier just to get the data from the asset and upload that. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/3237282-requestimagedataandorientationfo

Comment: When you say upload the data, do you mean like this:  `let selectedImage = pickedImages[0]`and then convert the chosen image to data in the following way: `let imageData = selectedImage.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8)`? Because this is how I upload images. But I just dont know how to do it with videos. Any ideas? @jnpdx

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting that. If you check the documentation I linked to, you'll see that PHAsset provides a function to get `Data` from the asset. There's another equivalent function for video as well. No need to use UIImage or any interim step.

Comment: Im sry, im really trying to wrap my head around this, but im not getting it. Would it be possible for you to provide me with some code i could go based on? @jnpdx

Comment: See [uploading from data in memory](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory).